# I cant understand how to declare database table of different category

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.7

I am trying to develop an application in laravel. there will be a different category with different form fields. like if someone provides PAN card Service then One kind of field. if someone provided Home Cleaning Service then different Kind of form field.

is it possible to declare a database table like that in laravel
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEFkq.png)

or I need to Declare Single Database table for every single Service

Comment: Please share your database design which you have tried ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to declare a database table shown in that image.
You can also Declare Single Database table for every single Service.

a good method will be to make it in one.
always name you tabels in plural 
name it **services** 
inside services

pan card serives 
home service 
more..
 you're good to go!

Comment: You can follow https://laravel.io/forum/09-13-2014-create-new-database-and-tables-on-the-fly

Comment: can you share your database design which you have tried .